# Continuity in finding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm wondering whether there's  "continuity" in the eigen vectors of different matrices corresponding to appropriate eigenvalues.

For instance, if we change certain elements in a matrix, can we measure  how does that change the eigen vectors?(maybe we can measure difference in normalized eigen vectors by angle?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up "perturbation theory".  It's simplest in the case of hermitian matrices with distinct eigenvalues, but can be done more generally as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. For instance, the two-dimensional identity matrix has any vector for eigenvector, and eigenvalue 1. If we rotate it ever so slightly, it will have no (real) eigenvectors.

Comment: But it will have complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  Who asked for real ones?

Comment: Ok, well, my point was that there is no automatic "continuity"; it all depends on the field we're talking about.

Comment: eigen vectors are not defined uniquely for equal eigen values. Thus any small peturbations may lead to jump in eigenvectors.